# How do I add permission_handler code to my main.dart page?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions, geolocation

I want to add the permission_handler plugin. Already added it to the **pubspec.yaml** file, but don't know exactly where to go from there. How do I actually add the code for **location** permissions to my **main.dart** page?

**main.dart** page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:athena/providers/app_state.dart';
import 'package:athena/providers/user.dart';
import 'package:athena/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:athena/screens/splash.dart';
import 'locators/service_locator.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();
  return runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AppStateProvider>.value(
        value: AppStateProvider(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>.value(
        value: UserProvider.initialize(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Athena',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserProvider auth = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    switch (auth.status) {
      case Status.Uninitialized:
        return Splash();
      case Status.Unauthenticated:
      case Status.Authenticating:
        return LoginScreen();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return MyHomePage();
      default:
        return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like this

```
Future<void> askLocationPermission() async {
    await Permission.location.request();
  }
```

Since you have added `home: MyApp()` as the home,

Go to `MyApp()`, and make it a StatefulWidget.

Then inside its initState(), call the function which requests permissions.

An example is shown below

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    askLocationPermission();
  }
```